Who wins this match removal game?
A box contains 300 matches. Two players take turns removing at least one but no more than half the matches in the box. The player who cannot move loses.
Which player has a winning strategy and how can they force a win?
Clarifications:
Once a match is removed from the box, it remains outside the box.  Players can’t remove a fractional number of matches.

Attribution:  Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience)

zero is no more than half of any number of matches, but I assume that taking zero matches doesn't count as a move?

@juicifer Thanks for your comment.  I have updated my question to address your zero matches concern.

What if 1 match is left?

@Nautilus If a player (call them A) leaves the other player (call them B) with just one match, then the other player B loses because they have no valid move.

There is a winning strategy for the player who goes

 first, and it starts by taking 45 matches.

Here's why:

 The only loss case is when there is only 1 match remaining - with any larger number of matches, a player will be able to take 1 match as a valid move. Therefore, whichever player can take all but 1 match will win. The only time a player can take all but 1 match is when there are 2 matches, so that's a win case, and if there are 3 matches, that's a loss case, as the only valid move is to take exactly 1 match, leaving 2 matches. So, to summarize:

 - player starts their turn with 1 match: loss
 - player starts their turn with 2 matches: win
 - player starts their turn with 3 matches: loss

 So, if a player can take all but 3 matches, they can guarantee a win. That's possible if there are 4, 5, or 6 matches left, but if there are 7 matches left, they'll have to take 4, which is more than half. The only options a player has if they start their turn with 7 matches is to take 1, 2, or 3, leaving the other player with 4, 5, or 6 - all win conditions, as previously established.

 So, if a player can take all but 7 matches, they can guarantee a win. To leave 7 matches, the maximum a player can have at the start of their turn is 14, and if they start their turn with 15 matches, they'll be forced to leave the other player with between 8 and 14 matches, guaranteeing that the other player will win.

Are you seeing the pattern?

 So far, our loss cases are 1, 3, 7, and 15 - all of the form $2^n-1$. This makes sense - if you have $2^n-1$ matches, you can take up to $2^{n-1}-1$ matches - but you can't take $2^{n-1}$ matches, and no matter how many matches you take, the other player can always respond such that you'll be left with $2^{n-1}-1$ matches, which will eventually lead you down to just 1 match.

So the ideal strategy is

 for the player who goes first to take 45 matches, leaving 255 for their opponent. On subsequent turns, they should take however many they need to leave 127, then 63, then 31, then 15, then 7, then 3, and eventually 1.



 If Player A leaving behind $n$ matches wins them the game, leaving behind $n+1$ to $2n$ matches loses the game, because Player B can just reduce it to an $n$-match game and win.  If Player A wins leaving behind $n$ matches, then no matter what B does, it always becomes a game whose second player (the one who left behind the game) loses. This means that, in the scenario in the previous paragraph, leaving behind $2n+1$ matches wins. With the first term being $1$, it's always $2^k-1$, meaning Player 1 can always force a win by leaving behind such a number, starting from $255$.

